# Randomly getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED only on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, chromium, tls1.2

Sometimes I get an error "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" for my application https://coach5.isxapps.com/ and the wired thing is that it only happen with google chrome and that too randomly.

It am not getting this error with Firefox or IE, Systems are scanned for any kind of viruses, spywares, malwares (no add-ons/extensions are installed on browser)

Attached are the screen-shots and [net-internal json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_p2J-AmpNxmT0Fqa1c0TTBVMGM) log files.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find any solutions for this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hello, some solution for this problem? I'm having the same issue in chrome.